# How to keep Tkinter window always on desktop

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

I use python 3.6 on windows 10. I want the tkinter window stay always on desktop even the desktop button is pressed. When I set topmost to true it stays always on desktop but it also precedes other windows. I want my window stays always on desktop without being the topmost of open windows.

Is there a way doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836489/running-a-command-on-window-minimization-in-tkinter) help at all?

Comment: Thanks @quamrana .  This [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836489/running-a-command-on-window-minimization-in-tkinter) solved my problem.